# IIS SMTP Relay to gmail fails occasionally

Tags: email, iis, ssis, smtp

I'm using IIS SMTP relay to gmail to send outbound emails. I create this email text file with SSIS script task and place the file in the Pickup directory. This script runs every 15 minutes. It works most of the time, but sporadically it fails with the following error message.

> Unable to deliver this message because the follow error was encountered: "Error is processing file in pickup directory.".
> The specific error code was 0xC00402CE.

I don't believe it has anything to do with the email format (receivers or sender) because the same email will successfully send later without generating the error. However, sometimes it gets "stuck" for hours at a time which I need to resolve. Also, if I simply copy/paste the file in the Pickup directory, it sends every time.

Comment: Server administration is off topic here. BTW, IIS SMTP is deprecated (same timeline with IIS 6), so you should stop using it.

Comment: Do you get any other error messages? For example, is there any relevant error message in Event Viewer.